# Usar funciones importadas en hug

Tags: python, json, api, rest, python-import

Para resumir, en clases estamos viendo API rest, json, etc, y la última clase vimos un ejemplo usando hug y encontré ésta "[guía](https://laesporadelhongo.com/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/laesporadelhongo.com/crear-apis-rest-con-python-y-hug/_index.html_gzip)" por ahí, la seguí y realicé todo hasta antes de

> Nota: Puesta en producción del método HTTP

La cosa es que, en base a eso quise hacer el mío propio, con unas funciones sencillas que realicé anteriormente en clases, pero a la hora de importar las funciones y utilizarlas dentro del hug, me sale éste error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/JsonIP.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(hug_ip("192.168.10.1",24))
  File "C:\Users\Cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hug\interface.py", line 440, in __call__
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hug\interface.py", line 432, in __call__
    result = self.interface(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hug\interface.py", line 129, in __call__
    return __hug_internal_self._function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:/Python/JsonIP.py", line 11, in hug_ip
    sub=subnet(ip,pref)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Aquí está el código, donde al principio importo mis funciones que ya he usado antes y funcionan, sospecho que algo está mal en mi forma de importarlas, es la primera vez que importo hehe:

```py
import hug
from functions import subnet
from functions import netdir
from functions import broadcast
from functions import hosts
@hug.cli()
@hug.get(examples="ip='192.168.10.1'&pref=24")
@hug.local()
def hug_ip( ip : hug.types.text, pref : hug.types.number, hug_timer = 3):
    """Gives info about a given network"""
    sub=subnet(ip,pref)
    net=netdir(ip,pref)
    bc=broadcast(ip,pref)
    hs=hosts(pref)
    return {
        'IP' : ip,
        'Prefijo' : pref,
        'Subnet Mask' : sub,
        'Network Address' : net,
        'Broadcast Address' : bc,
        'Available Hosts' : hs
        }
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(hug_ip("192.168.10.1",24))
```

El archivo está en E:\Python\ y las funciones que importo están en E:\Python\functions\ así que no sé si esté bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al parecer estás llamando a un módulo de Python y no a la función dentro de ese módulo.

Cuando tienes tus funciones distribuidas en distintos archivos `.py` con el mismo nombre de la función que contienen dentro, tienes que dar un paso más para poder ocupar dicha función en tu código principal.

A continuación te doy dos opciones que pueden ayudarte a acceder a ellas.

```
from functions.subnet import subnet # desde el módulo subnet dentro del paquete functions
                                    # importa la función subnet
from functions.netdir import netdir
from functions.broadcast import broadcast
from functions.hosts import hosts

def hug_ip(ip, pref, hug_timer = 3):
    sub=subnet(ip,pref)
    net=netdir(ip,pref)
    bc=broadcast(ip,pref)
    hs=hosts(pref)
```

En el ejemplo de arriba puedes navegar por los directorios o módulos con el estilo `moduloX.moduloY`.

```
from functions import subnet
from functions import netdir
from functions import broadcast
from functions import hosts

def hug_ip(ip, pref, hug_timer = 3):
    sub=subnet.subnet(ip,pref) # desde el módulo subnet usa la función subnet
    net=netdir.netdir(ip,pref)
    bc=broadcast.broadcast(ip,pref)
    hs=hosts.hosts(pref)
```

Al igual que en el ejemplo anterior puedes navegar con el mismo estilo, pero ahora haciendo la referencia desde el objeto importado de la forma `moduloX.funcionX`.

Existen muchas otras formas de importar módulos, para más información consulta https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Muchas gracias, estuve buscando pero era difícil encontrar mi problema específico en todo google hehe, y más cuando al parecer era tan simple.
Por eso terminé haciendo una cuenta aquí por recomendación de un amigo.
Y al parecer sirvió haha, gracias de nuevo.
Supongo que es más práctico si meto mis funciones que sean similares o funcionen para un mismo tema en un mismo archivo hehe.